# Laravel com erro no no composer install

Tags: php, laravel

eu movi o laravel para o servidor de homologação e quando rodei o composer install, tive esse problema.
alguém já teve algo assim?
na minha maquina que roda sob o vagrant roda liso.

O ambiente é laravel 5.4, redhat 7 e php 7

```
Generating optimized autoload files
> Illuminate\Foundation\ComposerScripts::postInstall
> php artisan optimize
PHP Warning:  Uncaught ErrorException: require(/var/www/html/gemeos-backend/vendor/rachidlaasri/laravel-installer/src/Providers/../routes/web.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/html/gemeos-backend/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/ServiceProvider.php:71
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/html/gemeos-backend/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/ServiceProvider.php(71): Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions->handleError(2, 'require(/var/ww...', '/var/www/html/g...', 71, Array)
#1 /var/www/html/gemeos-backend/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/ServiceProvider.php(71): require()
#2 /var/www/html/gemeos-backend/vendor/rachidlaasri/laravel-installer/src/Providers/LaravelInstallerServiceProvider.php(27): Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider->loadRoutesFrom('/var/www/html/g...')
#3 /var/www/html/gemeos-backend/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(574): RachidLaasri\LaravelInstaller\Providers\LaravelInstallerServiceProvider->register( in /var/www/html/gemeos-backend/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/ServiceProvider.php on line 71
PHP Fatal error:  Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider::loadRoutesFrom(): Failed opening required '/var/www/html/gemeos-backend/vendor/rachidlaasri/laravel-installer/src/Providers/../routes/web.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/pear:/usr/share/php') in /var/www/html/gemeos-backend/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/ServiceProvider.php on line 71


  [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException]
  Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider::loadRoutesFrom(): Failed opening requir
  ed '/var/www/html/gemeos-backend/vendor/rachidlaasri/laravel-installer/src/
  Providers/../routes/web.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/pear:/usr/share/ph
  p')


Script php artisan optimize handling the post-install-cmd event returned with error code 255
```

Comment: A pasta `/var/www/html/` tem permissão de escrita e esta associada ao seu usuário principal? Por acaso você não esta rodando em `root` algo né? Porque o composer não deve ser rodado em root, se fez algo anteriormente com root, talvez tenha criado pastas sem permissão.

Comment: a pasta /html é root:root porém a pasta do projeto é com meu usuário

Comment: Mas você não rodou anteriormente nenhum outro comando acidentalmente com `su`/`sudo`?

Comment: o único comando que eu rodei foi esse:
 sudo chown -R danilo.dorgam gemeos-backend/
para tirar o root da pasta e filhas

Comment: Danilo qual comando usou para instalar? Foi o `composer global require "laravel/installer"` e depois o `laravel new blog`?

Comment: no meu pc sim, nesse servidor ele pega do github enviando pelo jenkins

Comment: Danilo talvez seja algo que esteja desatualizado e o composer esteja misturando alguma coisa de versão, tente seguir os passos da resposta.

Answer (score 1):

Existem duas maneiras de instalar o Laravel, a primeira e talvez mais comum seja instalado o "laravel/installer", primeiro rode o comando em qualquer pasta, não precisa ser na onde irá criar o projeto:

```
composer global require "laravel/installer"
```

Isso irá instalar "globalmente", então o instalador irá permitir usar, claro que o composer precisa estar instalado globalmente também, para isso terá que adicionar `$HOME/.composer/vendor/bin` ao `$PATH` do sistema operacional.

O após garantir que esta tudo global, execute navegue até a pasta do Apache e tente criar um novo projeto:

```
cd /var/www/html
laravel new gemeos-backend2
```

Veja se o problema ocorre ainda.

A maneira alternativa, sem o **comando `laravel`** é instalar via `create-project` do composer, navegue até a pasta e execute o comando:

```
cd /var/www/html
composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel gemeos-backend3
```

---

### Resolvendo possíveis problemas

Pela mensagem de erro:

> Uncaught ErrorException: require(/var/www/html/gemeos-backend/vendor/rachidlaasri/laravel-installer/src/Providers/../routes/web.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/html/gemeos-backend/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/ServiceProvider.php:71

Presumo que algo ou tenha sido baixado na versão errada ou misturada, primeiro devemos garantir que tudo esteja atualizado, para atualizar o composer rode o comando:

```
composer self-update
```

Se não estiver global, rode:

```
php composer.phar self-update
```

Se estiver usando o Laravel/Installer então remova-o primeiro:

```
composer global remove laravel/installer
```

E então em seguida tente instalar novamente ele e criar um projeto:

```
composer global require "laravel/installer"
cd /var/www/html
laravel new gemeos-backend4
```

> **Nota:** mudei o nome da pasta (`gemeos-backend2`, `gemeos-backend3` e `gemeos-backend4`) para cada teste feito, acaso seja um problema de usuário/permissão
>
> **Nota:** o `laravel/installer` irá instalar a versão `5.5` do Laravel

Comment: eu percebi essa diferença de versão, no meu pc é a 1.4.2 e no servidor 1.5.1 será que um downgrade é uma boa?

Comment: @Danilo depende se estiver conflitando com outra lib, framework, verifica o teu composer.json. Uma nota, tanto o Laravel 5.1, quando 5.2, 5.3 e 5.4 ainda não mantidos e podem ser usados, o lançamento do 5.5 não impede o uso das versões anteriores.

Comment: meu laravel é 5.4, porém acho que não é ele, eu instalei a lib direto no servidor mas deu na mesma

Comment: @Danilo toda sugestões acima ocasionaram `Uncaught ErrorException: require(/var/www/html/gemeos-backend/vendor/rachidlaasri/laravel-installer/src/Providers/../routes/web.php)`?